# CSS fixed positon affected by Norton toolbar

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I'm trying to fixed position an EU cookie notification to the bottom right of screen. I've set it 1 em up from bottom and 1 em in from right. It works until my Norton Security Safe Search toolbar loads, then it moves down and doesn't show the 1 em bottom spacing and puts the button against the bottom of screen. I had to add a height property else it would put the button outside of the div background color.

Changing the position bottom to a higher number doesn't seem to do anything when the Norton toolbar loads.

```
<div class="cookiebar">
    <p>Cookies are used on our website to give you the best experience and by using our site you agree to their use as described in our <a href="#">cookie policy.</a></p>
    <button><a href="#">OK</a></button>
</div>

.cookiebar {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 1em;
        right: 1em;
        background: #777;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: right;
        max-width: 34em;
        padding: 1em;
        height: 7em;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .cookiebar button {
        background: #c17ccf;
        color: #FFF;
        margin-top: 1em;
        padding: .4em 1.2em;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Also when the Norton toolbar loads it seems to add an inline style to the cookiebar class
    
    <div class="cookiebar" style="top: 853px !important;">

Comment: Did you ever get any help or find any solutions to this? It's maddening!

Comment: No it's still the same. I was hoping someone could show a way to override the !important style that gets added by Norton. I don't understand why the Norton toolbar makes the cookie bar jump up and down the page when scrolled.